# How to show legend in a combined plot of many lists,

Tags: plotting, graphics, legending

I am having trouble with adding a legend to a plot. The example I discuss here is simpler than my real problem, but describes it well.

I have a vector, called X with dimensions (100 x 6). I use the command `ListPlot` to plot one row of X at a time:

```
plotX={};
Do[
p1=ListPlot[X[[i]]];
AppendTo[plotX,p1],
{i,1,Length[X]}];
```

Therefore, the list `plotX` contains six list plots with 100 points each. To show all the plots, I use the command `Show`

```
Show[plotX]
```

Now I want to create a legend for this graph, for example `{"x1","x2","x3","x4","x5","x6"}`. How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: If you have version 9 you can use the `PlotLegends` option.

Comment: @b.gatessucks - Unfortunately I have version 7, however `PlotLegends` work in version 7 too, in fact sometimes I used it, but in this case I can't to resolve the problem with that command

Comment: It would help if you add to the question information about what happens when you try to use `PlotLegends` in your version.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky - Simple problem like:
`Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotLegend -> {"sine", "cosine"}]`
I have no problem, but in my example gives me error and a message: An unr"ecognized option name ("PlotLegends`PlotLegend") was encountered while reading a GraphicsBox."

Comment: @Emanuele as I said, it helps if you add the information to the question, that way it is properly visible.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky - If I insert `PlotLegend->{"x1"}` inside the third row of code, I get a graph with a legend with only one item instead six ones.

Comment: If you are going to stay on V7 then once you get more familiar with Mathematica I'd recommend you try @Jens legends code.

Answer (score 3):

I would plot all the data sets you have in one go :

```
$Version
(* "7.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (February 18, 2009)" *)

data = Table[Sin[i] + j, {i, 1, 100}, {j, 1, 6}];

Needs["PlotLegends`"]

ListPlot[Transpose[data], Joined -> True,  
     PlotLegend -> {"x1", "x2", "x3", "x4", "x5", "x6"}]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: I have to plot a list of point not a function therefore I can't do the graph in this way.

Comment: I am not plotting a function, I used `Sin` just to make up some data. Have a look at my `data` or post yours and I'll update my answer.