# Legends in combined Plot and ListPlot

Tags: plotting, legending, version-7

I have a set of data

```
plotgamma6 = {{0.1, 14/15}, {0.2, 17/20}, {0.3, 11/15}, {0.4, 
43/60}, {0.5, 2/3}, {0.6, 13/20}, {0.7, 7/12}, {0.8, 17/30}, {0.9,
 17/30}, {1., 31/60}, {1.1, 31/60}, {1.2, 7/15}, {1.3, 
7/15}, {1.4, 9/20}, {1.5, 9/20}, {1.6, 9/20}, {1.7, 13/30}, {1.8, 
5/12}, {1.9, 2/5}, {2., 2/5}, {2.1, 2/5}, {2.2, 23/60}, {2.3, 
23/60}, {2.4, 11/30}, {2.5, 11/30}, {2.6, 11/30}, {2.7, 
7/20}, {2.8, 1/3}, {2.9, 1/3}, {3., 1/3}, {3.1, 1/3}, {3.2, 
1/3}, {3.3, 19/60}, {3.4, 19/60}, {3.5, 19/60}, {3.6, 3/10}, {3.7,
 3/10}, {3.8, 4/15}, {3.9, 1/4}, {4., 7/30}, {4.1, 13/60}, {4.2, 
13/60}, {4.3, 13/60}, {4.4, 13/60}, {4.5, 13/60}, {4.6, 
13/60}, {4.7, 13/60}, {4.8, 13/60}, {4.9, 13/60}, {5., 13/60}};
plotgamma10 = {{0.1, 93/100}, {0.2, 89/100}, {0.3, 83/100}, {0.4, 
    81/100}, {0.5, 37/50}, {0.6, 18/25}, {0.7, 17/25}, {0.8, 
    16/25}, {0.9, 61/100}, {1., 59/100}, {1.1, 14/25}, {1.2, 
    14/25}, {1.3, 13/25}, {1.4, 13/25}, {1.5, 49/100}, {1.6, 
    23/50}, {1.7, 23/50}, {1.8, 9/20}, {1.9, 9/20}, {2., 
    43/100}, {2.1, 43/100}, {2.2, 21/50}, {2.3, 41/100}, {2.4, 
    2/5}, {2.5, 19/50}, {2.6, 37/100}, {2.7, 9/25}, {2.8, 7/20}, {2.9,
     17/50}, {3., 33/100}, {3.1, 29/100}, {3.2, 29/100}, {3.3, 
    29/100}, {3.4, 27/100}, {3.5, 13/50}, {3.6, 6/25}, {3.7, 
    6/25}, {3.8, 6/25}, {3.9, 6/25}, {4., 6/25}, {4.1, 21/100}, {4.2, 
    1/5}, {4.3, 1/5}, {4.4, 19/100}, {4.5, 9/50}, {4.6, 9/50}, {4.7, 
    4/25}, {4.8, 4/25}, {4.9, 4/25}, {5., 4/25}};
```

which I plot using ListPlot

```
Needs["PlotLegends`"]
a = ListPlot[{plotgamma6, plotgamma10}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {0, 1}}, AxesLabel -> {"gamma", "quantity"}, 
 PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.02], PlotLegend -> {"N=6", "N=10",}, 
 LegendPosition -> {1.1, -0.4}, Joined -> {True, True}, 
 PlotMarkers -> Automatic]
```

Now, I also want to plot a function which needs to be compared with the above data, i.e.,

```
    f[z_] := Exp[-z/2] BesselI[0, z/2];
    b = Plot[-2 f'[z], {z, 0, 5}, PlotLegend -> "Theory", 
  LegendPosition -> {1.1, -0.4}]
```

Now, I want to combine these two plots into one, so I use

```
Show[a,b]
```

However, this gives a messed up plot!
If I remove the plot legends from both the plots, then the combined plot looks reasonable though.
But I really want to retain the plot legends. How would you combine these two plots? It doesn't matter to me how you plot these data, i.e., if you use `Show` or some other function.

Please note that my question is closely related to 
[How to show legend in a combined plot of many lists,](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16191/how-to-show-legend-in-a-combined-plot-of-many-lists)

However, that question wasn't answered fully either.

Thanks!
dbm368

Comment: What _Mathematica_ version are You working on?

Comment: I am using Mathematica 7. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

The plots are misaligned because plot b doesn't have the exact same options as a, which causes it to be drawn slightly different. If you give the same options to plot b (`PlotRange`, `AxesOrigin`, and `AxesLabel`)

```
b = Plot[-2 f'[z], {z, 0, 5}, PlotLegend -> "Theory", 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {0, 1}}, LegendPosition -> {1.1, -0.4}, 
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, AxesLabel -> {"gamma", "quantity"}]
```

then you can use `Show[a,b]` to get them lined up:
[image: output of Show[a,b]]

Note that you'll have to move the "Theory" legend to get the "N=10" legend to show.

Alternatively, you could generate a set of data from the theoretical functions, and plot that in one go with your other data:

```
plottheory = Table[{z, -2 f'[z]}, {z, 0, 5, 0.01}];

ListPlot[
  {plotgamma6, plotgamma10, plottheory},
  AxesOrigin->{0,0}, PlotRange->{{0,5},{0,1}}, AxesLabel->{"gamma","quantity"},
  PlotStyle->PointSize[0.02], PlotLegend-> {"N=6","N=10","theory"},
  LegendPosition->{1.1,-0.4}, Joined->True, 
  PlotMarkers->{\[FilledSmallSquare],\[FilledSmallCircle],""}
]
```

This gives a slightly nicer output:

[image: output of ListPlot[{},...]]

Answer (score 1):

You can also handle this legending problem with the functions I defined (and just updated) in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4028/245). You have to copy all the definitions in the first code block of that answer, and then do this:

```
a = ListPlot[{plotgamma6, plotgamma10}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {0, 1}}, AxesLabel -> {"gamma", "quantity"}, 
   PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.02],
   Joined -> {True, True}, PlotMarkers -> Automatic];

f[z_] := Exp[-z/2] BesselI[0, z/2];
b = Plot[-2 f'[z], {z, 0, 5}];

c = Show[a, b];

styles = extractStyles[c]
```

> `{{Directive[Hue[0.67,0.6,0.6],PointSize[0.02]],Directive[Hue[0.906068,0.6,0.6],PointSize[0.02]],Directive[Hue[0.67,0.6,0.6]]},{\[FilledCircle],\[FilledSquare]}}`

The above output is a list whose first element contains the styles of the three different lines in `c`, and whose second element is a list of plot markers. The latter has only two members, `{\[FilledCircle],\[FilledSquare]}`. I now want to use this information in the function `legendMaker` of the linked answer, but for this I need to add an invisible "dummy" plot marker so that I can pass three line styles and three plot markers to the function:

```
Overlay[{c, legendMaker[{"N=6", "N=10", "Theory"},
   PlotStyle -> styles[[1]],
   PlotMarkers -> Append[
     styles[[2]], ""]]}, Alignment -> {Right, Top}]
```

[image: plot with and w/o markers]

Comment: Nice explanation in both answers and nice trick of adding a dummy plot marker!

Comment: @LeoFang Thanks for pointing this question out to me earlier... even if my solution isn't fully automatic, at least it looks more modern than the old `PlotLegends` package.

Comment: it's way more modern!