# Clear labelling gray-scale plots

Tags: plotting, graphics, legending

I am plotting a number of functions (at least 4 in one plot) with a legend. Needless to say, it is important that it is clear from the legend which line belongs to which function. I tried to play around with the `PlotStyle`, but I'm not getting them to look all that different. The paper it will be published in demands grey-scale pictures, so I can't use different colours.

I was hoping to use `PlotMarkers` instead, but I found that these only exist within the `ListPlot` but not in `Plot`. In theory I could overlay a `Plot` with a `ListPlot`, but then it wouldn't show in the legend. What is the best way to add the markers in both the plot and the legend?

This is a minimal working example of something to which I'd to add `PlotMarkers`.

```
Needs["PlotLegends`"];
Plot[{Sin[x], Sin[x + π/4], Sin[x + π/2], Sin[x + 3π/4]}, {x, 0, 2π},
     PlotLegend -> {"#1", "#2", "#3", "#4"},
     PlotStyle -> {DotDashed, Dashed, Dashing[0.01], Dotted}]
```

Comment: You can Use `Show` [like here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/28141/5478).

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? I'd know a couple of uses for `Show[]`, but none of them is extremely helpful here. That is what I meant in the question: when I use `Plot` and `ListPlot` within the same `Show[]` command, it doesn't quite cover it.

Comment: What version of Mathematica are you using?

Comment: I'm using Mathematica 9.

Comment: Then I suggest looking at `PlotLegends` (instead of the package you are loading). You can e.g. use it directly in @Kuba's answer (I personally always had problems with the `PlotLegends`
 package...)

Comment: @PinguinDirk This package is a real patience teacher :) I have made incorrect assumption about a version we are dealing with :/

Comment: patience teacher is a nice way to put it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the functions, you can always make a `ListPlot`

```
f1[x_] := Sin[x];
f2[x_] := Sin[x + \[Pi]/4];
f3[x_] := Sin[x + \[Pi]/2];
f4[x_] := Sin[x + 3 \[Pi]/4];
(*some arbitrary functions*)

(*create table from a function*)
dataf[f_, xmin_, xmax_, ndata_] := Table[{x, f[x]}, {x, xmin, xmax, (xmax - xmin)/ndata}];

Needs["PlotLegends`"];
ListPlot[{dataf[f1, 0, 2 \[Pi], 20], dataf[f2, 0.01, 2 \[Pi], 20],
dataf[f3, 0.02, 2 \[Pi], 20], dataf[f4, 0.03, 2 \[Pi], 20]}, 
PlotLegend -> {"f1", "f2", "f3", "f4"},LegendPosition -> {1.1, -0.4},
LegendShadow -> False, Joined -> {True, False, True, False},
PlotMarkers -> Automatic]
```

It will give you this

[image: plot]

Answer (score 2):

```
  h = Graphics[{Black, #1}, PlotRange -> #2] &; 

  ListPlot[Transpose@Table[{Sin[x], 
                            Sin[x + \[Pi]/4], 
                            Sin[x + \[Pi]/2], 
                            Sin[x + 3 \[Pi]/4]}, {x, 0, 2 \[Pi], .1}], 
           PlotLegend -> {"#1", "#2", "#3", "#4"}, Joined -> True, 
           PlotStyle -> Directive@{Black, Thick},  ImageSize -> 500,
           PlotMarkers -> {{h[Disk[], 1], .04}, {h[Disk[], 2], 0.01}, 
                           {h[Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}], .5], .04}, 
                           {h[{Thick, 
                               Line[{{0, 0}, {0, 10}}]}, {{-1, 1}, {0, 10}}], .05}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Fantastic, thanks! The black isn't terribly important, as th default colours are changed to grey-scale anyway.

Comment: @Jelle I have used custom markers because in grayscale automatic are not clear imo. Next time be patient with accpeting, I'm sure someone will show something nicer :)