# Legends in a combined Plot and ListPlot

Tags: legending

This question is related to the previously asked question
[Legends in combined Plot and ListPlot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28138/legends-in-combined-plot-and-listplot).

Since *Mathematica* 9 introduced new option `PlotLegends`, I was tempted to use built-in facility. (With the previous versions, I used the LevelScheme package).

Consider a data set

```
A = {#, #^2} & /@ Range[100];
B = {#, #^1.8} & /@ Range[100];
```

and its theoretical prediction

```
A1 = x^2;
B1 = x^1.8;
```

I want to plot them together using `ListPlot` and `Plot`, respectively. And show them together with a single, combined legend.

Also, I want to have user defined markers (e.g, filled-diamond, size = 15, joined -> false and so on) and set the style of the plot (e.g., Red, Thickness[0.01], Dashed and so on).

I wonder if these requirements can be achieved by the built-in `PlotLegends` in *Mathematica* 9.

#### Edit

The code below is what I tried, but I could not get the desired result.

```
MakeExponent[x_Integer] := "\*SuperscriptBox[10," <> ToString[x] <> "]"
tick = {10^#, MakeExponent[#]} & /@ Range[-10, 10, 1];

A = {1/#, #^2} & /@ Range[100];
B = {1/#, #^1.5 - 1} & /@ Range[100];
A1 = {1/#, #^2} & /@ Range[100];
B1 = {1/#, #^1.5 - 1} & /@ Range[100];
ALegend = Style[ "Legend A", 12, Black, FontFamily -> "Courier"];
BLegend = Style[ "Legend B", 12, Black, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"];
A1Legend = Style[ "Legend A1", 12, Black, FontFamily -> "Courier"];
B1Legend = Style[ "Legend B1", 12, Black, FontFamily -> "Courier"];
AMarker  = Style["\[FilledCircle]", 10, Orange];
BMarker  = Style["\[FilledDiamond]", 10, Purple];
A1Marker  = Style["\[LongDash]", 15, Blue];
B1Marker  = Graphics[Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}]];
XLabel = Style[ Sqrt[x^2], 17];
YLabel = Style[t^2 , 17];
```

And then I tried

```
pic1 = ListLogLogPlot[ {A, B, A1, B1},
  Axes -> False,
  Frame -> True,
  Joined -> {False, False, True, True},
  PlotStyle -> {, , Blue, Red},
  FrameLabel -> {XLabel, YLabel} ,
  PlotMarkers -> {AMarker, BMarker, ,},
  PlotLegends ->
   Placed[
    PointLegend[
     {ALegend, BLegend, A1Legend, B1Legend},
     LegendMarkers -> {AMarker, BMarker, A1Marker, B1Marker},
     LegendMarkerSize -> {30, 10},
     ], {0.8, 0.7}
    ],
  FrameTicks -> {{tick, None}, {tick, None}},
  FrameTicksStyle -> 16
]
```

Comment: Try removing the extra comma after the `LegendMarkerSize` option

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A few minor errors corrected (mostly extra commas):

```
MakeExponent[x_Integer] := "\*SuperscriptBox[10," <> ToString[x] <> "]"
tick = {10^#, MakeExponent[#]} & /@ Range[-10, 10, 1];

A = {1/#, #^2} & /@ Range[100];
B = {1/#, #^1.5 - 1} & /@ Range[100];
A1 = {1/#, #^2} & /@ Range[100];
B1 = {1/#, #^1.5 - 1} & /@ Range[100];
ALegend = Style["Legend A", 12, Black, FontFamily -> "Courier"];
BLegend = Style["Legend B", 12, Black, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"];
A1Legend = Style["Legend A1", 12, Black, FontFamily -> "Courier"];
B1Legend = Style["Legend B1", 12, Black, FontFamily -> "Courier"];
AMarker = Style["\[FilledCircle]", 10, Orange];
BMarker = Style["\[FilledDiamond]", 10, Purple];
A1Marker = Style["\[LongDash]", 15, Blue];
B1Marker = Style["\[LongDash]", 15, Red];
XLabel = Style[Sqrt[x^2], 17];
YLabel = Style[t^2, 17];
pic1 = ListLogLogPlot[{A, B, A1, B1}, Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
  Joined -> {False, False, True, True}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}, 
  FrameLabel -> {XLabel, YLabel}, PlotMarkers -> {AMarker, BMarker}, 
  PlotLegends -> 
   Placed[PointLegend[{ALegend, BLegend, A1Legend, B1Legend}, 
     LegendMarkers -> {AMarker, BMarker, A1Marker, B1Marker}, 
     LegendMarkerSize -> {30, 10}], {0.8, 0.7}], 
  FrameTicks -> {{tick, None}, {tick, None}}, FrameTicksStyle -> 16]
```

[image]