# Rotate one plot and add legend tp another

Tags: plotting, legending, labeling, rotation

I have one function and some data that I want to plot together.

I have two questions.

1. How can I have a legend for `dataMC` list plot?
2. How can I rotate the `CMontkhab2` function plot a little to get it closer to the green points?

This is my code

```
Show[
  Plot[CMontkhab2, {r, 0.2, 1.1}, 
    PlotLegends -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(C\), \(PFC + RELK\)]\)(r)"}, 
    PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.006]}], 
  {ListPlot[{dataMC}, 
     PlotStyle -> {{Green, PointSize[0.02]}}]}, 
  LabelStyle -> {Bold, Gray, 20}, ImageSize -> Scaled[0.7], 
  Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"r", "C(r)"}, LabelStyle -> Bold]
```

and this is my plot

[image]

Here is the `CMontkhab2` function I want to rotate a bit, so it gets closer to the green points:

```
CMontkhab2=
  8 + 0.15 E^(-4.94941 r^2) (-104.167 + 219.33 r - 684.841 r^3) + 
  0.15 (-59.2126 + 68.9522 r - 14.5717 r^3) + 
  0.7 (-59.5597 + 60.1605 r - 12.6466 r^3)
```

Comment: `1-How can i data plot put the label` could you rephrase this? It is not clear what you are asking.  `2-How can I rotate the function plot to match the green points?` Is the function you have an expression? But If you want the function to match exactly the points, then why not just plot the points? Also, without showing the data or code for the function, it will make it hard to answer this fully.

Comment: 1-I want to put a legend for data plot @nasser

Comment: Can you fit a function to `dataMC` and plot that instead?

Comment: For question 1 maybe [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28138/legends-in-combined-plot-and-listplot) could help.

Comment: In fact these green points is correct criterion and i should can Match the blue line on it.That's why I need to rotate blue line. and my function(Blue line function) have an expression.@nasser

Comment: I have no function for dataMC.And I should not do that.Because these functions are related to potential And I should not change them@ aardvark2012

Comment: You might be able to do something with `Rotate[Plot[...]]`. But isn't the function `CMontkhab2` just the wrong one? Couldn't you use [`FindFit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindFit.html) or [`NonlinearModelFit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonlinearModelFit.html) to fix the function rather than rotating the plot?

Comment: I can not change that function CMontkhab2.And I do not want to be totally fit.I just want to get closer to the green points by rotation@ aardvark2012

Comment: I have no familiarity with the theory behind whatever you're doing, but I'm pretty sure rotating your curve to meet those points is not the right way to do what you need to do.

Comment: You are right . thankue so much@ J. M.♦

Comment: and How can i for dataMC plot put the legend@ J. M.♦

Comment: you are amazing.With  your sentence, my problem was solved.@ J. M.♦

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question about adding a legend to the data list plot, try adding the option `PlotLegends -> {"Data"}` to that plot.

Here the code.

Your function

```
f[r_] :=
  8 + 0.15 E^(-4.94941 r^2) (-104.167 + 219.33 r - 684.841 r^3) + 
  0.15 (-59.2126 + 68.9522 r - 14.5717 r^3) + 
  0.7 (-59.5597 + 60.1605 r - 12.6466 r^3)
```

Some contrived data since you didn't give us a list of your data points.

```
data[u_, x0_] :=
  Table[RotationTransform[u Degree, {x0, f[x0]}][{x, f[x]}], {x, .2, 1., .05}]
pts = data[-.25, .6];
```

The plot with legends for both curve and data points

```
Show[
  Plot[f[r], {r, 0.2, 1.1}, 
    PlotLegends -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(C\), \(PFC + RELK\)]\)(r)"}, 
    PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.006]}],
  ListPlot[pts,
    PlotLegends -> {"Data"},
    PlotStyle -> {{Green, PointSize[0.02]}}],
  LabelStyle -> {Bold, Gray, 12},
  ImageSize -> Scaled[.8],
  Frame -> True,
  FrameLabel -> {"r", "C(r)"}]
```

[image: plot]

Note: I made the contrived data by rotating your function about a certain point on it. Is that not ironic?